# Fully developed flow in cylinder coordinates

Tags: fluid-dynamics, conservation-laws, symmetry, flow, navier-stokes

I have a flow that is:

- steady (time derivative is zero)
- fully developed
- in-compressible (constant density)
- no slip at the wall
- axis-symetric (theta derivative is zero)
  The configuration of the pipe is:
  [image: pipe picture]

Using mass conservation of an in-compressible fluid gives me:

$$ \nabla \dot V = 0 $$
[image: del dot velocity]

Assuming the fluid travels in the z-direction (ignore the x in the figure), I am left with
$$\frac{d}{dr}(rv_r) = 0$$

since $$ \frac{d}{dz}v_z = 0 $$ for fully dev flow (correct me if I am wrong) and any derivative wrt to theta is equal to zero due to the flow being axis-symmetric

Apply no-slip boundary conditions and we get $v_r = 0$

However, when I use naiver-stokes in the theta direction using the above assumptions, I am left with:

$$ 0 = v[\frac{1}{r}\frac{d}{dr}(r \frac{d}{dr}v_{\theta}) + \frac{d^2}{dz^2 } v_{\theta}] $$

**Question**: The answer says that $\frac{d^2}{dz^2 } v_{\theta} = 0 $ and I do not know why since $$v_{\theta} \neq 0$$ from what I can tell. So what justification can we use to cancel this term?

Comment: Your only dependence of $v$ is on $r$. I don't see what your problem is, quite frankly.

Comment: Cart: $$ V = V(u[x,y,z] , v[x,y,z] , z[x,y,z]) $$ Cylinder: $$V = (v_r[r , \theta , z], v_{\theta}[r , \theta , z] , v_z[r , \theta , z])$$. I don't see how we know which components are equal to zero in cylinder, unlike in cart. e.g. fluid purely flows in x-dir means u(x , 0 , 0) for example.